# Stretch table to fit jquery mobile listview

Tags: html, css, listview, jquery-mobile

Good day,

Could someone please assist me with making HTML table match the height and width of jquery-mobile listview?  Attached is the snapshot of the goal I am trying to acheive.[image: trying to stretch table to match listview dimensions]

I first tried using <strike>data-split-icon approach</strike>, but abandoned it because of challenge moving icon to the left and it created multiple clickable segments which I don't want.

I am now trying to fit basic HTML table within the dimensions of jquery-mobile listview.  My first attempt was to use standard HTML table and style it but table didn't stretch.  My second attempt is to use CSS table so use ul element as table, li as table-row:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="d" data-icon="false" class="listviewborder customul" style="margin-right:3px;margin-left:3px;">
   <li class="customli">
       <div class="div-table-col" align="center">Image</div>
       <div  class="div-table-col">Date1</div>
       <div  class="div-table-col">Date2</div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

and CSS:

```
        ul.customul
        { 
            display: table;
            border:1px solid  black;
            width:auto;
        }

        li.customli 
        { 
            display: table-row;
            display:table-row;
            width:auto;
            clear:both;
        }

        .div-table-col
        {
            float:left;
            display:table-column;         
            width:auto;  
            border:1px solid  black;
        }
```

I researched similar questions and came up with this approach, but it's still not working.  I think I'm on the right track but the table still not matching the dimensions of the listview.  Could somebody please suggest what I am missing or what else needs to be done here to make it work?

Thank you,

Victor.

Comment: Check grids in JQM demos -- http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/grids/  - i created a basic demo for you -- https://jsfiddle.net/es6uvt70/

Comment: Thank you.  This answers my question.